# yarn: cannot find module

Tags: typescript, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

[image]

I have a yarn workspace set up with folders `public` and `server`. I am using TypeScript in VS Code. On any module that doesn't have types pre-installed with the package, I get the error in VS Code:

```
Cannot find module 'x'
```

However, the IntelliSense will show `x` as a suggestion. I have both `x` and `@types/x` and it seems like it's no difference if I install `@types/x`. Thanks

```
Windows 1909 (Latest)
Visual Studio Code 1.43 (Latest)
TypeScript ^3.8.3 (Latest)
Yarn 2.0.0-rc.30 (Latest)
```

Also, I tried to find type roots for yarn, but didn't. Could someone please tell me where the type root directry is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Similar issue here. This error is coming from the linter; I think it's checking inside the package lock file (which does not exist as yarn is using `yarn.lock`).

Please check these in your VSCode user `settings.json`:

```
"eslint.packageManager": "yarn",
"prettier.packageManager": "yarn",
"npm.packageManager": "yarn"
```

These settings have worked for me. YMMV.

EDIT: changed punctuation

Comment: Didn't work for me, plus the first two says it's unknown

Comment: eslint and prettier are resolved automatically in the latest version of VSCode (1.80.0)

Answer (score 14):

Have a look at the instructions here: https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks

> Smart IDEs (such as VSCode or IntelliJ) require special configuration for TypeScript to work. This page intends to be a collection of settings for each editor we've worked with - please contribute to this list!

For example when using a "vscode" IDE execute:

```
yarn dlx @yarnpkg/pnpify --sdk vscode
```

The above command will wire up your vscode project to rely on yarn, i.e. it adds the `sdks` folder within your `.yarn` config and also tells your IDE to use it, by adding the following to your `settings.json`:

```
"typescript.tsdk": ".yarn/sdks/typescript/lib",
"typescript.enablePromptUseWorkspaceTsdk": true
```

**Hint**: Yarn caches its packages in form of zip archives. So in order to be also able to inspect your `node_modules` imports managed by yarn, you can install the [ZipFS extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=arcanis.vscode-zipfs)

> This extension adds support into VSCode to read files directly from zip archives. It's maintained as part of the Yarn toolchain. Using this extension together with the Yarn SDK will allow you to seamlessly open & edit files from your cache.

Comment: Thanks for posting this documentation link. Unfortunately, I'm on yarn 1 and this requires yarn 2.

Comment: For yarn 3, the command is `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode` . Also the .vscode folder must be in the VSCode workspace root (move it and fix the paths inside if necessary).

Answer (score 14):

From the [docs](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks):

#### To support features like go-to-definition a plugin like ZipFS is needed.

1. Run the following command, which will generate a new directory called `.yarn/sdks`:

   ```
   yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode
   ```
2. For safety reason VSCode requires you to explicitly activate the custom TS settings:
3. Press ctrl+shift+p in a TypeScript file
4. Choose "Select TypeScript Version"
5. Pick "Use Workspace Version"

Comment: I tried the accepted answer first (set up a brand new project with yarn 3), but steps 4 and 5 are what fixed my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It took almost half an hour to solve this. The steps are:

1. Install [ZipFS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=arcanis.vscode-zipfs) extension for VSCode because you might need to see some definitions.
2. Run `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode` to install VSCode support for Yarn.
3. Open command palette with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and choose "Select TypeScript version".
4. Choose "Workspace Version" that starts with `.yarn`.
5. On terminal, do `yarn config set nodeLinker node-modules` and then `yarn`.