# I'm trying to configure a React App using Yarn Berry + Vite, but the cannot find modules error won't go away in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Here are the steps to reproduce the problem.

1. `yarn create vite PROJECT_NAME`
2. `cd PROJECT_NAME`
3. `yarn install`
4. `yarn set version berry`
5. `yarn add @yarnpkg/sdks -D`
6. `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode`
7. Accept the notification from VSCode
8. Set the TypeScript version to Use Workspace Version in VSCode
9. Refresh VSCode.

After going through these steps I keep seeing the error 'cannot find moules' in VSCode.

I guess this error is caused by the change to Typescript 5. Using Vite + Yarn Berry config with Typescript 4 no `cannot find modules` error in VSCode.

Is there any way to solve these problems?

Comment: What's the error code? Is this coming from eslint? Typescript? Can you transpile the code?

Comment: Quite an old question, thanks for the answer. I will look for the error code and let you know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [yarn: cannot find module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60778047/yarn-cannot-find-module)